# python generator object confusion

Tags: python, generator

I have a confusion what's wrong with my code:

```
users = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Number1', 'age': 11},
         {'id': 2, 'name': 'Number2', 'age': 12},
         {'id': 3, 'name': 'Number3', 'age': 13},
         {'id': 4, 'name': 'Number4', 'age': 14}]

_keys = ('name', 'age')

data_by_user_id = {u.get('id'): (u.get(k) for k in _keys) for u in users}
```

data_by_user_id looks like:

```
{1: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f3c12c31050>, 2: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f3c12c310a0>, 3: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f3c12c310f0>, 4: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f3c12c31140>}
```

but after iteration:

```
for user_id, data in data_by_user_id.iteritems():
    name, age = data
    print user_id, name, age
```

result is different than I expected:

```
1 Number4 14
2 Number4 14
3 Number4 14
4 Number4 14
```

Can anyone explain me what am I doing here wrong?
I know I can use list comprehension instead of generator but I'm trying to figure what's the issue with my code

Thanks!

Comment: Well you *unpack* the generator into two elements `name, age`. So now you force Python to evaluate it. But a problem is that you now exhausted the generators.

Comment: I understand that, but why I'm getting the same result for every generator?

Comment: because the generators are done lazily. So all `u`s point to the same dictionary (the last one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already know, generator expressions are evaluated lazily. The evaluation of `dict.get` is deferred until the generator expression is consumed at what time `u` in the current scope is the last dictionary your list:

```
>>> u = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Number1', 'age': 11}
>>> _keys = ('name', 'age')
>>> gen = (u.get(k) for k in _keys)
>>> # update u
>>> u = {'id': 4, 'name': 'Number4', 'age': 14}
>>> list(gen)
['Number4', 14]
```

One *obvious* way to fix this is to use a **list comprehension** instead. Another way, not as good as the first, is to put the generator expression in a function, and bind the current value of `u` to that function by means of a default argument:

```
data_by_user_id = {u.get('id'): lambda x=u: (x.get(k) for k in _keys) for u in users}

for user_id, data in data_by_user_id.iteritems():
    name, age = data()
    print name, age
```

---

```
Number1 11
Number2 12
Number3 13
Number4 14
```

Answer (score 3):

Your expression in the dictionary comprehension statement:

```
(u.get(k) for k in _keys)
```

is a *generator expression*. It means that you construct a generator. A generator is an iterable object that evaluates elements lazily: it does not get the elements from `u`, it postpones this operation until you for instance call `next(..)` on it to obtain the next element. So you construct such a dictionary.

In the body of the `for` loop, you write:

```
name, age = data
```

with `data` being the value of the item. Now this means that you ask Python to "*unpack*" the iterable. This will work given the iterable yields exactly the same amount as elements as the number of variables on the left, so in this case two. As a result you will exhaust the generator and obtain the results of the iterator. Next you print these elements.

Note that after the `for` loop, all the values of the dictionary will be *exhausted* generators, so your `for` loop has side effects. In order to prevent that, you better materialize the generators.

**EDIT**: another problem here, is that you use `u` in the dictionary comprehension, which is not scoped very well. As a result, if the **`u` variable is changed, the result of the generators will change as well**. This is problematic since at the end of the dictionary comprehension, all generators will work with the *last* dictionary.

You can solve the problem by generating a local scope:

```
{u.get('id'): (lambda u=u: (u.get(k) for k in _keys))() for u in users}
```

Now it generates the expected output:

```
>>> users = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Number1', 'age': 11},
...          {'id': 2, 'name': 'Number2', 'age': 12},
...          {'id': 3, 'name': 'Number3', 'age': 13},
...          {'id': 4, 'name': 'Number4', 'age': 14}]
>>> 
>>> _keys = ('name', 'age')
>>> data_by_user_id = {u.get('id'): (lambda u=u: (u.get(k) for k in _keys))() for u in users}
>>> for user_id, data in data_by_user_id.iteritems():
...     name, age = data
...     print user_id, name, age
... 
1 Number1 11
2 Number2 12
3 Number3 13
4 Number4 14
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help